# Maximizing a particular integral / functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations, bounded-variation

I have a (probably simple) question whose answer seems obvious but I cannot prove it. It relates to the calculus of variations.

Let scalar 
$A = \Re[\int_a^bB(x)C(x)dx$], where $B$ and $C$ map $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$. Find the scalar function $B(x)$ which maximizes $A$ under the constraints that $\int_a^b|B(x)|^2=k^2$ for $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_a^b|C(x)|^2=q^2$ for $q\in\mathbb{R}$.

If necessary, assume $B$ and $C$ are everywhere finite and/or real and/or continuously differentiable and/or whatever else you think is necessary.

Intuition tells me that the solution must be $B(x)=pC(x)^\ast$ where $p=k/q^\ast$ and $\ast$ indicates complex conjugate, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Are $B$ and $C$ a mapping like $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Also, is $C$ fixed?  Or do you want to find this function as well? Are the functions continuous?

Comment: Hi TylerHG, thanks for the question. Yes, treat C as fixed and yes, B and C map real to complex. If it is helpful to forget the complex business then do so and treat everything as a real.

Comment: In response to TylerHG's comments I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Lagrange multipliers? When I did this, using the functional
$$L = \mathfrak{R}[ \int BC \; dx + \lambda \int |B^2| \; dx]$$

and take the usual Euler Lagrange differential, the result you state pops out.